# Node js characters returned in wrong encoding "€" = "ï¿½"

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding

Simple program using restify to handle calls. I have this test function that I send back "€" from. The result in browser is "ï¿½". How come?

```
server.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(200, "€");
});
```

I googled this and found people with charcter encoding problems who have solved it by setting charset to utf-8:

```
res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

no difference. So I tried:

```
res.set({
  'Content-Type' : 'text/plain',
  'charset' : 'utf-8'
});
```

Now I got back ï¿½ instead of "ï¿½" that is no quotation marks around the response.

If i save my code as UTF-8 instead of the default encoding used in visual studio (Western Europe (Windows) Codepage 1252) i get back "Ã¶". Apparantly it has an effect on the result, but not the desired.

Obviously there is something I have missed with handling of character encodings in nodejs.

If i view the response in fiddler, the response is correctly displayed as ö, but in the browsers it is displayed as "Ã¶". To make sure no viewer plugin in chrome is messing with the result (since it displayed correctly in fiddler) i tried it in IE and Firefox too.

Here is a raw view of fiddler response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
charset: utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, Api-Version, Response-Time
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Api-Version, Request-Id, Response-Time
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-MD5: RPLFC4OPkpcNLBHi+pi8fQ==
Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 12:41:11 GMT
Server: restify
Request-Id: 365e0550-d7a3-11e4-b7d8-43b88a1e9b3c
Response-Time: 1

ö
```

Comment: And you saved the files as UTF8 as well ?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry that i forgot to mention that as one of my troubleshooting steps and the result of it. If i save my code as UTF-8 instead of the default encoding used in visual studio (Western Europe (Windows) Codepage 1252) i get back "Ã¶". Apparantly it has an effect on the result, but not the desired.